# is there a reason for why I have users with weird IDs (i.e: '0', '1'... ) being created randomly in the database (firebase)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple chat app where you can sign up for an account, sometimes users with weird IDs pop up in the database.
Signing up does not cause this problem, these users appear to be created randomly.
[[image: example of mentioned weird user IDs]]

I tried deleting these users but it keeps popping up. The IDs seem to be indexed starting from 0

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74949516/edit) your question and add the code that is not working as intended?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Dharmaraj asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: We need to see the specific code that creates the users in Firebase. We also need to know your coding platform so please add the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.